# How to access mongodb via the plugin fastify-mongodb

Tags: mongodb, fastify

My plugin looks like

```
import fp from 'fastify-plugin';
import mongodb from 'fastify-mongodb';

export default fp(async (fastify) => {
  fastify.register(mongodb, {
    url: 'mongodb+srv://dbuser:password@cluster0.otigz.mongodb.net/myapp?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
  });
});
```

and my handler looks like

```
const postJoinHandler = async (
  request: any,
  reply: any
): Promise<{ id: string; name: string }> => {
  try {
    const { username, password } = request.body; 

    const test = await reply.mongo.db.users.insertOne({
      username,
      password,
    });
    console.log(test);

    return reply.code(201).send(username);
  } catch (error) {
    request.log.error(error);
    return reply.send(400);
  }
};
```

Expected it to insert the username and password into the collection named users, but it didn't? and the error is `Cannot read property 'db' of undefined`

I also tried

```
reply.mongodb.users.insertOne({...
```

and

```
    const test = await request.mongodb.collection('users');

    test.insertOne({
      username,
      password,
    });
    console.log(test);
```

and

```
const test = await this.mongo.db.collection('users'); //<= Object is possibly 'undefined'
```

Routes look like

```
import { FastifyPluginAsync } from 'fastify';
import { postJoinSchema, postLoginSchema } from '../schemas/auth';

const auth: FastifyPluginAsync = async (fastify): Promise<void> => {
  fastify.post('/auth/join', postJoinSchema);
  fastify.post('/auth/login', postLoginSchema);
};

export default auth;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `mongo` decorator is attached to the `fastify` instance, not to the `request` nor `reply` object.

You should move your handlers into the routes file and read for `fastify.mongo` or use a named function as the handler.

In the latter case, the handler has `this` bounded to the `fastify` instance.

```
async function postJoinHandler (
  request,
  reply
) {
  try {
    const { username, password } = request.body; 

    const test = await this.mongo.db.users.insertOne({
      username,
      password,
    });
    console.log(test);

    reply.code(201)
    return username
  } catch (error) {
    request.log.error(error);
    reply.code(400);
    return {}
  }
};
```

Comment: I now get this error 'error TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.' and 'An outer value of 'this' is shadowed by this container.'

Comment: It is a TS issue. I'm not a TypeScript developer